# How to load some associations by default?

Tags: cakephp

If I want to get all Articles with comments, I need to do

```
$articles->find()->contain('Comments')->...
```

However, I might want to fetch the articles in many places all over my project and in nearly all cases load the comments as well. Currently I need to write a `->contain('Comments')` again and again.

Is there a way I can define Comments as contained by default if I don't explicitly say I don't want them to be loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it into a behavior into a beforeFind callback.
This way you can attach it to the model, and if needed you could even unload the behavior.

Comment: If there's a fair number of places where you would need to unload the behavior, and as a result find that to be a bit clunky, another option would be to make a [custom finder](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods) that you could access like `$articles->find('withComments')`. It's more code than @mark's solution, but less than what you're doing now.

Comment: True, you can do that. But `find()->contain('Comments')` isn't that much longer than `find()->find('comments')` etc. So I don't think you gain much as long as it doesn't also come with more customization inside the finder.